# How can I create a VS Code keybinding with three keys (two being non-modifier keys)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

Trying to bind cursorWordEndRight to `alt`+`;`+`l` so that the command triggers when I press all three simultaneously, - *not as a chord* - but it highlights red in my Keybindings.json file and says `You won't be able to produce this key combination under your current keyboard layout. Key or key sequence (separated by space)`

Does VS Code not allow you to have keybinds with two letters? Any way to achieve this?

Comment: you can do `alt+; alt+l`, use a key prefix

Comment: I need it as a simultaneous keybind that I can press over and over again, not as a chord.

Comment: WIth @rioV8's keybinding, you can keep the `Alt` key depressed and hit the other two keys, no need to treat it as two separate keychords functionally, although they are.  And no, I don't think you can make a keybinding with two separate letters like that (only the modifier keys can be multiples).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't, but you could work around it by using chords as long as one of the keys is a modifier. Basically, write every possible sequence of the keys plus the modifier(s) as a binding. Ex.

```json
{
    "key": "alt+b alt+n",
    "command": "cursorUp",
},
{
    "key": "alt+n alt+b",
    "command": "cursorUp",
},
```

Limitations:

- It doesn't work when holding the combination down.
- Note that versions of VS Code before the March 2023 release only support chords with two steps (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/175253)
- It can get unwieldy to define the keybindings the more non-modifier keys you want (quadratic growth).